# Correct R syntax for an interaction term and a polynomial in a mixed effect linear model

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, lme4, polynomials

I am building a linear mixed effect model and unfortunately it looks like I might need both an interaction and polynomial term. The `rd_dist_seg variable` occurs in both the interaction and the polynomial. I just wanted to check if my syntax is correct and the model is actually doing what I think it is doing. Is this correct? Thanks for any help.

```
sp.model<- lme(Log_TOR ~ rd_dist seg*dir + dir+ poly(rd_dist_seg,3) + ELC_Mode, data=sprm, random=~1|id)
```

Comment: ````rd_dist_seg*dir```` includes rd_dist_seg, dir, and their interaction. I think you can try using a new variable ````x_new = rd_dist_seg*dir````. This should make sure the formula is right.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful!